# EU Temporary Residence Card and Visa application

Tags: visa, canada, eu

Suppose, I have a TRC from **Germany**. Then, I go to London,**UK** for a job.

Now, can I apply for a **Canadian** student Visa from London?

Comment: Once you have a visa, you can fly from wherever; it doesn't matter where you applied for the visa.  But whether you can apply while you're in London probably depends on your immigration status in the UK at the time you file the application.  What will that be?

Comment: @phoog, i will be on job visa.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can apply from another country if you have been legally admitted and allowed to reside there. If there are circumstances which you feel need explanation, include a [statement on your application](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1017&top=16) why you have not applied in your normal country of residence.